# How to get inputs when the html is loaded and when they change in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events, javascript-objects

I am using JS to pass data to Python. First, when the HTML is loaded I want to collect the values and this works, the issue is when the value changes, it doesn't change.

Please excuse me, I am quite new to JS. Here is my working code:

```
<input type="date" id="start-date" name="start-date" value="2019-10-10"/>
<label for="date">to</label>
<input type="date" id="end-date" name="end-date" value="2020-05-10"/>

<script>
  document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var start_date = document.getElementById("start-date").value;
    var end_date = document.getElementById("end-date").value;

    $.ajax({
      url: "/dates",
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        start_date: start_date,
        end_date: end_date,
      },
    });
  };
</script>
```

Comment: 1. The script is below the <input>s so there's no need to wait for the document being loaded 2. the code doesn't contain any attempt at adding an onchange or oninput handler to them

Comment: oh so no need to wait for the document to update? if I dont the values will be none at first

Comment: The document is parsed from top to bottom, so you would only have to wait for window's onload event if the script were included above the <input>s (because they wouldn't exist yet at the time the script runs)

Comment: How I'd implement this: https://jsfiddle.net/5aosu2xt/

Comment: This works very well but its none when the document is first loaded. is there a way around that?

Comment: can you add this as an answer? I will accept, thanks so much

Comment: Not for me? Adding `console.log(start_date.value)` as the first line of sendDates() nicely shows 2019-10-10 in the console when I load the page

Comment: no I mean sending the data to that endpoint so that I can retrieve with python

Comment: what do you mean "its none when the document is first loaded"? When I open the fiddle and look at the console, both dates appear in the request URL just fine

Comment: Oh I mean its not in the endpoint request yet until I entered start or end values, like I dont see the default value in the request endpoint  until I click the inputs

Comment: Again, if you check my fiddle, you will see that merely running it causes a request for `https://fiddle.jshell.net/dates?start_date=2019-10-10&end_date=2020-05-10` without doing anything, so in other words it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

`document.onreadystatechange`  does not make any sense.

You need a change event

Here I delegate from document.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { // only needed if the script is not after the date elements
  document.addEventListener("change",function(e) { // this can be narrowed to a closer container like a form
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (!tgt.matches("[type=date]") return; // not a date change
    let start_date = document.getElementById("start-date").value;
    let end_date = document.getElementById("end-date").value;
    $.get("/dates", {start_date, end_date },function(data) {
      console.log(data); // returned from server
    });
  });
});
```

Alternative using the same event handler for both dates

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { // only needed if the script is not after the date elements
  const startDateField = document.getElementById("start-date");
  const endDateField = document.getElementById("end-date");
  const dateChange = e => { 
    let start_date = startDateField.value;
    let end_date = endDateField.value;
    $.get("/dates", {start_date, end_date },function(data) {
      console.log(data); // returned from server
    });
  };
  startDateField.addEventListener("change",dateChange);
  endDateField.addEventListener("change",dateChange);
});
```